Rails Heroku deployment fails: Could not find gems, Failed to install gems via Bundler
So I have a Rails application that I am trying to push to Heroku. When I run git push heroku master, I get:
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 1369, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1369/1369), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (906/906), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1369/1369), 35.15 MiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 1369 (delta 755), reused 829 (delta 398), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (755/755), done.
remote: Updated 169 paths from d8b5ada
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.5.6
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.2.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.5.6
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Could not find rails-7.1.3.4, sprockets-rails-3.5.1, pg-1.5.6, puma-6.0.2,
remote:        importmap-rails-2.0.1, turbo-rails-2.0.5, stimulus-rails-1.3.3, jbuilder-2.12.0,
remote:        tzinfo-data-1.2024.1, bootsnap-1.18.3, sendgrid-ruby-6.7.0, devise-4.9.4,
remote:        letter_opener-1.10.0, activerecord-7.1.3.4, actiontext-7.1.3.4,
remote:        htmlbeautifier-1.4.3, base64-0.2.0, bigdecimal-3.1.8, mutex_m-0.2.0,
remote:        tailwindcss-rails-2.6.1, actioncable-7.1.3.4, actionmailbox-7.1.3.4,
remote:        actionmailer-7.1.3.4, actionpack-7.1.3.4, actionview-7.1.3.4, activejob-7.1.3.4,
remote:        activemodel-7.1.3.4, activestorage-7.1.3.4, activesupport-7.1.3.4,
remote:        railties-7.1.3.4, sprockets-4.2.1, nio4r-2.7.3, tzinfo-2.0.6, msgpack-1.7.2,
remote:        ruby_http_client-3.5.5, bcrypt-3.1.20, responders-3.1.1, launchy-3.0.1,
remote:        timeout-0.4.1, globalid-1.2.1, nokogiri-1.16.6, mini_magick-4.13.1,
remote:        ruby-vips-2.2.1, websocket-driver-0.7.6, zeitwerk-2.6.16, mail-2.8.1,
remote:        net-imap-0.4.14, net-smtp-0.5.0, rails-dom-testing-2.2.0, racc-1.8.0,
remote:        rack-3.1.6, rack-session-2.0.0, rack-test-2.1.0, rails-html-sanitizer-1.6.0,
remote:        builder-3.3.0, erubi-1.13.0, marcel-1.0.4, concurrent-ruby-1.3.3,
remote:        connection_pool-2.4.1, drb-2.2.1, i18n-1.14.5, minitest-5.24.1, irb-1.13.2,
remote:        rackup-2.1.0, rake-13.2.1, thor-1.3.1, addressable-2.8.7, childprocess-5.0.0,
remote:        mini_portile2-2.8.7, ffi-1.17.0, mini_mime-1.1.5, date-3.3.4,
remote:        net-protocol-0.2.2, loofah-2.22.0, rdoc-6.7.0, reline-0.5.9, webrick-1.8.1,
remote:        public_suffix-6.0.0, psych-5.1.2, io-console-0.7.2, stringio-3.1.1 in cached
remote:        gems or installed locally
remote:        Bundler Output: Could not find rails-7.1.3.4, sprockets-rails-3.5.1, pg-1.5.6, puma-6.0.2,
remote:        importmap-rails-2.0.1, turbo-rails-2.0.5, stimulus-rails-1.3.3, jbuilder-2.12.0,
remote:        tzinfo-data-1.2024.1, bootsnap-1.18.3, sendgrid-ruby-6.7.0, devise-4.9.4,
remote:        letter_opener-1.10.0, activerecord-7.1.3.4, actiontext-7.1.3.4,
remote:        htmlbeautifier-1.4.3, base64-0.2.0, bigdecimal-3.1.8, mutex_m-0.2.0,
remote:        tailwindcss-rails-2.6.1, actioncable-7.1.3.4, actionmailbox-7.1.3.4,
remote:        actionmailer-7.1.3.4, actionpack-7.1.3.4, actionview-7.1.3.4, activejob-7.1.3.4,
remote:        activemodel-7.1.3.4, activestorage-7.1.3.4, activesupport-7.1.3.4,
remote:        railties-7.1.3.4, sprockets-4.2.1, nio4r-2.7.3, tzinfo-2.0.6, msgpack-1.7.2,
remote:        ruby_http_client-3.5.5, bcrypt-3.1.20, responders-3.1.1, launchy-3.0.1,
remote:        timeout-0.4.1, globalid-1.2.1, nokogiri-1.16.6, mini_magick-4.13.1,
remote:        ruby-vips-2.2.1, websocket-driver-0.7.6, zeitwerk-2.6.16, mail-2.8.1,
remote:        net-imap-0.4.14, net-smtp-0.5.0, rails-dom-testing-2.2.0, racc-1.8.0,
remote:        rack-3.1.6, rack-session-2.0.0, rack-test-2.1.0, rails-html-sanitizer-1.6.0,
remote:        builder-3.3.0, erubi-1.13.0, marcel-1.0.4, concurrent-ruby-1.3.3,
remote:        connection_pool-2.4.1, drb-2.2.1, i18n-1.14.5, minitest-5.24.1, irb-1.13.2,
remote:        rackup-2.1.0, rake-13.2.1, thor-1.3.1, addressable-2.8.7, childprocess-5.0.0,
remote:        mini_portile2-2.8.7, ffi-1.17.0, mini_mime-1.1.5, date-3.3.4,
remote:        net-protocol-0.2.2, loofah-2.22.0, rdoc-6.7.0, reline-0.5.9, webrick-1.8.1,
remote:        public_suffix-6.0.0, psych-5.1.2, io-console-0.7.2, stringio-3.1.1 in cached
remote:        gems or installed locally
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to *****.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/*****.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/*****.git'

I have tried the solutions found on this question, but nothing works (I get the same error). Everything runs fine on my local machine, so I don't know why it is not working on Heroku.
I do also want to ask: Are you supposed to run the commands found on this question from your local server, or from the heroku shell for your app? Because I have tried running the commands from the heroku shell but to no avail:
$ heroku run bash --app *****
Running bash on ⬢ *****... up, run.4316 (Basic)
~ $ bundle install
bash: bundle: command not found

Here is my gemfile:
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.2.2'

# Core Rails gems
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3", ">= 7.1.3.4"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
gem 'puma', '~> 6.0.0'
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "tzinfo-data" # Removed platforms as Heroku uses Linux
gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'

# Other gems
gem "devise", "~> 4.8", ">= 4.8.1"
gem "letter_opener"
gem "activerecord"
gem 'actiontext', '7.1.3.4'
gem "htmlbeautifier"
gem "base64"
gem "bigdecimal"
gem "mutex_m"
gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"
gem 'tailwindcss-rails'
# gem "bundler", '2.5.13'

# Development and test-specific gems
group :development, :test do
  gem "rufo"
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

And here is my gemfile.lock:
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    actionmailbox (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      activejob (= 7.1.3.4)
      activerecord (= 7.1.3.4)
      activestorage (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      actionview (= 7.1.3.4)
      activejob (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
    actionpack (7.1.3.4)
      actionview (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
      racc
      rack (>= 2.2.4)
      rack-session (>= 1.0.1)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
    actiontext (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      activerecord (= 7.1.3.4)
      activestorage (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.11)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
    activejob (7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
    activerecord (7.1.3.4)
      activemodel (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      timeout (>= 0.4.0)
    activestorage (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      activejob (= 7.1.3.4)
      activerecord (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
    activesupport (7.1.3.4)
      base64
      bigdecimal
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5)
      drb
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      mutex_m
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.7)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 7.0)
    base64 (0.2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.20)
    bigdecimal (3.1.8)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.18.3)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.3.0)
    capybara (3.40.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.11)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (5.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.3.3)
    connection_pool (2.4.1)
    crass (1.0.6)
    date (3.3.4)
    devise (4.9.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dotenv (3.1.2)
    dotenv-rails (3.1.2)
      dotenv (= 3.1.2)
      railties (>= 6.1)
    drb (2.2.1)
    erubi (1.13.0)
    ffi (1.17.0)
    globalid (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
    htmlbeautifier (1.4.3)
    i18n (1.14.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.12.2)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
    importmap-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    io-console (0.7.2)
    irb (1.13.2)
      rdoc (>= 4.0.0)
      reline (>= 0.4.2)
    jbuilder (2.12.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    launchy (3.0.1)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      childprocess (~> 5.0)
    letter_opener (1.10.0)
      launchy (>= 2.2, < 4)
    loofah (2.22.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.4)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    mini_magick (4.13.1)
    mini_mime (1.1.5)
    mini_portile2 (2.8.7)
    minitest (5.24.1)
    msgpack (1.7.2)
    mutex_m (0.2.0)
    net-imap (0.4.14)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.2)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.5.0)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.7.3)
    nokogiri (1.16.6)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.2)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.5.6)
    psych (5.1.2)
      stringio
    public_suffix (6.0.0)
    puma (6.0.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.8.0)
    rack (3.1.6)
    rack-session (2.0.0)
      rack (>= 3.0.0)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rackup (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 3)
      webrick (~> 1.8)
    rails (7.1.3.4)
      actioncable (= 7.1.3.4)
      actionmailbox (= 7.1.3.4)
      actionmailer (= 7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      actiontext (= 7.1.3.4)
      actionview (= 7.1.3.4)
      activejob (= 7.1.3.4)
      activemodel (= 7.1.3.4)
      activerecord (= 7.1.3.4)
      activestorage (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.1.3.4)
    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    railties (7.1.3.4)
      actionpack (= 7.1.3.4)
      activesupport (= 7.1.3.4)
      irb
      rackup (>= 1.0.0)
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    rake (13.2.1)
    rdoc (6.7.0)
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
    regexp_parser (2.9.2)
    reline (0.5.9)
      io-console (~> 0.5)
    responders (3.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      railties (>= 5.2)
    rexml (3.3.1)
      strscan
    ruby-vips (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    ruby_http_client (3.5.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    rufo (0.18.0)
    selenium-webdriver (4.10.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sendgrid-ruby (6.7.0)
      ruby_http_client (~> 3.4)
    sprockets (4.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.5.1)
      actionpack (>= 6.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stimulus-rails (1.3.3)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    stringio (3.1.1)
    strscan (3.1.0)
    tailwindcss-rails (2.6.1)
      railties (>= 7.0.0)
    thor (1.3.1)
    timeout (0.4.1)
    turbo-rails (2.0.5)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    tzinfo-data (1.2024.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.3.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0, < 4.11)
    webrick (1.8.1)
    websocket (1.2.10)
    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.16)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  actiontext (= 7.1.3.4)
  activerecord
  base64
  bigdecimal
  bootsnap
  capybara
  devise (~> 4.8, >= 4.8.1)
  dotenv-rails
  htmlbeautifier
  image_processing (~> 1.2)
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  letter_opener
  mutex_m
  pg (~> 1.1)
  puma (~> 6.0.0)
  rails (~> 7.1.3, >= 7.1.3.4)
  rufo
  selenium-webdriver
  sendgrid-ruby
  sprockets-rails
  stimulus-rails
  tailwindcss-rails
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.2.2p53

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.14

Note: I have tried adding the x86_64-linux under platforms in my gemfile.lock, then running bundle install, then git push heroku master, and it still did not work.
I also tried replacing BUNDLED WITH in my Gemfile.lock with:
BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.25

and committing and pushing but still the same issue.

What does your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock look like? What source is defined in Gemfile. What remote and PLATFORMS are defined in the Gemfile.lock?

@spickermann Check the edit. the source defined in the Gemfile is https://rubygems.org. In Gemfile.lock the remote is https://rubygems.org/ and the PLATFORMS is ruby

What does the build pack stack on Heroku look like?

@spickermann When I go to the settings page on my app, the Stack says "heroku-22".
Under Buildpacks, it says "heroku/ruby"

Did you push the code with an vendor/cache folder? Then remove the cache subfolder and try again.

You might consider trying to purge the build cache heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname using the Heroku Repo plugin

@spickermann So I guess that was my issue (needed to delete vendor/cache)! I want to give you the bounty since you helped me resolve the issue. Should I just give it to you on the answer you already made, or did you want to make another answer that gives the solution?

When deploying a Ruby on Rails on Heroku and getting an error message from Bundler that is telling it Could not find <list of gem> in cached gems or installed locally, then this might be caused by various reasons:

A vendor/cache folder in the application's repository
When there is a vendor/cache folder in the application's repository, then Bundler will try installing gem from that repository. If the repository is empty, missing gems or only include gems that were installed on a different platform, then it will fail.
To fix this, try deleting the cache subfolder in vendor before deploying.

Bundler not configured to install gems for the platform used on Heroku.
Quote from the Heroku documentation about using Bundler:

An app’s Gemfile.lock that is generated with Bundler 2.2.3 locally may not work on Heroku unless the Linux platform is explicitly    “locked”:
$ bundle lock --add-platform ruby
$ bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
$ bundle install
$ git add . ; git commit -m "Bundler fix"


Adding missing platform with bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux, running bundle install again, and then committing the changes to git and pushing to Heroku might fix the issue.



Same issue. After running the first 3 commands, nothing changed in either my gemfile or my gemfile.lock. Maybe something is not happening the way it should. I believe what is supposed to happen is something after the bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux and bundle install. As in, it should add x86_64-linux as a platform in Gemfile.lock, but it doesn't.

So I even tried adding the x86_64-linux under platforms in my gemfile.lock, then running bundle install, then git push heroku master, and it still did not work.
